# Can I know in advance where it will stop before Scrollview stops scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can I know in advance where the Scrollview will stop before scrolling stop? I have consulted relevant online materials, but it seems that there is no relevant topic. I am making a magic app to know where it will scroll before Scrollview stops, so that I can modify the value there in advance

My attempt: mark when it starts to slow down and stop, but the sliding distance between them is uncertain, so I haven't finished my idea yet

Comment: I don’t know for certain but there is a delegate function that will tell you the velocity and acceleration when the user stops scrolling so I guess you could use that. I’ll have a play and see if I can work something out too.

Comment: It seems complicated and requires a lot of calculation? I will go to check the relevant contents immediately. Thank you for your help. If you can, can you use obj-c language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scroll view delegate method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619385-scrollviewwillenddragging

This will tell you the intended target offset when the deceleration finishes.

It is intended to be used to change the target offset. For instance if you want to make sure it aligns with the content you have tween it finishes.

But you don’t have to change it. You can just return the target offset but use that to change the content like you mentioned.